# How to do CV in logistic regression when predicton doesn't work?

Tags: regression, logistic

Having fit a logistic regression, I want to do cross-validation.

How can I do this? The usual method of computing predictions and calculating the accuracy doesn't work ... because ... there's nothing to predict. My logistic regression predicts a *probability*, which I can't compare to anything, as my data is binary 1/0 values.

You could try and predict 1 if the predicted probability is greater than 0.5 and vice-versa, but that only works for trivial cases: in my case, the probabilities are always less than 0.5, so this method would always predict y = 0.

Comment: You could use the logloss on validation set predictions as your validation metric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> there's nothing to predict

Certainly there is. And your logistic regression outputs probabilistic predictions. Which is a Very Good Thing. So what you need to do is to assess the quality of probabilistic predictions. (Out-of-bag, as always in cross-validation.)

The tool to do so is [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules), which map probabilistic predictions and corresponding outcomes to scores. In your case, the simplest approach would be to use the [logarithmic scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule).

Suppose your prediction for a particular instance $i$ to be of class 1 is $\hat{p}_i$. If the instance in fact is of class 1, the score is $s_i:=\log\hat{p}_i$. If it is of class 0, $s_i:=\log(1-\hat{p}_i)$. (It's always the log of the predicted probability for the *actual* class.)

The you just sum over the scores, $S:=\sum_i s_i$. A higher total score is better. (Some people use the opposite convention and *minimize* the score, then they work with *negative* logs.)

You may be interested in [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352) to [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) Or in [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352).